# Method [validate] does not exist error in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have just started learning laravel.
I am using laravel 5.2.29
I am getting error when running the code:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>   BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 107:
>   Method [validate] does not exist.

Here is the error line displayed:

```
in Controller.php line 107
2.at Controller->__call('validate', array(object(Request), array('action' =>        'required', 'name' => 'required'))) in NiceActionController.php line 31
3.at NiceActionController->validate(object(Request), array('action' => 'required', 'name' => 'required')) in NiceActionController.php line 31
4.at NiceActionController->postNiceAction(object(Request))
5.at call_user_func_array(array(object(NiceActionController), 'postNiceAction'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 80
6.at Controller->callAction('postNiceAction', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
7.at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(NiceActionController), object(Route), 'postNiceAction') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
8.at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
9.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
10.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
11.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
12.at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
13.at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(NiceActionController), object(Route), object(Request), 'postNiceAction') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
14.at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\NiceActionController', 'postNiceAction') in Route.php line 174
15.at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
16.at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
17.at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
18.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
19.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
20.at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
21.at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
22.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
23.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
24.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
25.at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
26.at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
27.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
28.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
29.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
30.at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
31.at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
32.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
33.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
34.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
35.at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
36.at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
37.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
38.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
39.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
40.at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
41.at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
42.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
43.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
44.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
45.at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
46.at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
47.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
48.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
49.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
50.at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
51.at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
52.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
53.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
54.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
55.at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
56.at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
57.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
58.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
59.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
60.at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
61.at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
62.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
63.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
64.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
65.at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
66.at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
67.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
68.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
69.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
70.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
71.at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
72.at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
73.at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
74.at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
75.at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
76.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
77.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
78.at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
79.at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'),         array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
80.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
81.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
82.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
83.at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
84.at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
85.at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
86.at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

My route code:

```
<?php


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
})->name('home');

Route::group(['prefix'=>'do'], function(){


    Route::get('/{action}/{name?}', [
        'uses' => 'NiceActionController@getNiceAction', 
        'as' => 'niceaction'  //router name same as ->name('routername')
    ]);



    Route::post('/', [

        'uses' => 'NiceActionController@postNiceAction',
        'as'   => 'benice'

    ]);

});

});
```

My Controller code is given below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NiceActionController extends Controller
{
public function getNiceAction($action, $name=null)
{
    return view('actions.'.$action, ['name' => $name]);

}

public function postNiceAction(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [

           'action' => 'required',
           'name' =>'required'

       ]);

            return view('actions.nice',            ['action'=>$request['action'],'name'=>$this->transformName($request['name'])]);

}
private function transformName($name)
{
    $prefix='KING';
    return $prefix.strtoupper($name);
}
}
```

My base main controller "controller" has following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;


class Controller extends BaseController
{
use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

}
```

Am i missing anything????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to extend the `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` class which uses the necessary `ValidatesRequests` trait that implements the required `validate` method.

So in your `NiceActionController` class just **remove this line**:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
```

That way this line:

```
class NiceActionController extends Controller
```

Will extend the proper `Controller` class from the same namespace (more precisely `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`), which includes the necessary traits and which already extends that `Illuminate\Routing\Controller` class (aliased as `BaseController`).

Comment: Now, I can't see {{$error}} on my view. The code goes like this :  `code`  @if(count($errors)>0)

        <div>
            <ul>

                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                @endforeach

            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif........Am i missing anything?

Comment: And this happens when the validation fails? Because the `validate` method from the `ValidatesRequests` trait will redirect back with input and errors if validation fails.

Comment: yes when validation fails, i don't see any error message..... i have a text input, if there is no value entered, the validation should display error like ' the name field is required'...

Comment: Is there any output if you add this to your view `{{ dump($errors) }}`? (just place it before the code that displays the errors.

Comment: i placed {{ dump($errors) }}and also tried{{ dump($error) }} before the {{ $error }} ....it doesn't display any error when i leave the text field blank....

Comment: Ok, errors are not displaying when i put my route in this route group: ..............Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){ }..............when i don't use this, the errors are showing fine....any way to solve it?...

Answer (score 2):

To display errors, simply remove the line below and the closing `)}`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
```

> As of 5.2, routes.php is by default already called in the context of a ['middleware'=>'web'] by RouteServiceProvider.
>   // But in routes.php default generation of auth routes, the Route::group call is still happening by default - so if you delete that Route::group
>   // declaration from routes.php the application then correctly shows errors.